# Compiled c++ output file displays random character at end of program?

Tags: c++, terminal, output

Not sure if this is an appropriate question, but just recently I've noticed that when I run a C++ program in the terminal when it exits it has a % sign after the last output. For example a hello world program says "hello world%". What is this and how do I get rid of it? I'm on OS X, shell is zsh. Unless I am crazy it has never done this until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I can think of off hand:

1) You aren't printing a carriage return, so the % prompt appears at the end of the printed text instead of on the next line. (Is the % your standard prompt in the shell?)

2) You are printing past the end of a buffer and getting a random character as a result.

I'd guess #1 based on what you describe, but both could cause the behavior.

Comment: @user2780518 if the answer solved your problem I recommend you accept the answer.

Comment: Will do, first time user of this place.